# How to return an indexed array object to a getJSON request in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, getjson

I am sending an Indexed Array to a PhP file in server side using getJSON. I guess I should better use associated array, but indexed array works fine and data are received at the server. I can process my Array at server and can store the array elements inside a file at server by referring to it's element using $results[i], but when I sending the whole array as a callback response, it sends "Array" only.
Here is the callback response I am sending to the client:

```
 echo $_GET['callback']. '('. "{'response' : " . "'". $results . "'}" .')';
```

if I say

```
 echo $_GET['callback']. '('. "{'response' : " . "'". $results[1] . "'}" .')';
```

it works and sends the element number 1 to the client. But I need to send the whole array.

Thanks for helping in advance.If code is needed, pls let me update.
saeid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insted of creating json object yourself rinventing the wheel)...use `echo json_encode` buili in function

```
echo json_encode(array('response'=> $results))
```

JQUERY

```
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
     console.log(data.response); //check your browser console..
})
```

Comment: I am using Indexed Array not associated array, can I then use "=>" to create the array?

Comment: yes.. you can... if you get rhe response in getJSON... try console.log(data.response)

Comment: thanks dude, I did the changes like this:  echo_GET['callback'].json_encode(array('response '=> $results)); and it succeeds by sending this to the client. jQuery18006218043297994882_1363080697837{"response":["109","621","863","1375","1623","2888","3167","3355","4255","4627","4918","6948","6964","8092","8282","8379","8460","8719","9136","9316"]}
Now, I fail to read the response and display to the user. How should I access to these numbers? my caller method is $.getJSON('http:/../server.php?callback=?', {input:array}, function(res)..} . Accessing array elements using res[i] fails. thank dude

Comment: Sorry bipen, I am new in jquery and webprogramming. I do that because wanna process the results inside the client code. I have the get as follows: $.getJSON('/sort/server/server.php?callback=?', {input:array}, function(res)
     {
     
          $('#Sorted_Array').text(res[1]+" Something");}, type='json'); 
   }//callJSON

Comment: then you can do...`echo json_encode(array('response '=> $results,'callback'=>GET['callback']))` and get in client by `res.callback`

Comment: Thanks, I get 
{"response ":["114","257","385","610","645","873","991","2196","2836","3105","3590","4211","4417","4833","5048","6109","6770","6957","7903","8351"],"callback":"jQuery1800968345012050122_1363088034484"} with an error of Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: When I use echo $_GET['callback'].json_encode(array($results)); I get this results jQuery18003248368250206113_1363088197446[["126","321","622","1204","1480","2325","2486","3169","4309","4539","5335","5436","5476","6489","7587","8458","8656","8917","8943","9706"]] but don't know if it is correct

Comment: I manage to get the result from the server and publish them on the screen. However, I am unable to access the array element individually yet, which in my case is not very important. I accept @bipen response which containt the key method of json_encode(array('response'=> $results)). I slightly changed the format and it worked for me. Thanks bipen.

Comment: welcome @Espanta..sorry, i was away...anyways gald that you got the answer... cheers... have fun coding... and let me know if there is problems stills...:)